# Sitecore Wrong Media File Path

Tags: sitecore, media-library

When I add an image through Media Library in RichTextEditor, the image path will be like this,

`<img src="~/media/A9DCE5769ED7445CA76F984FAF63A7D7.ashx?la=en" />`

However, when I publish page item with this image, the image doesn't appear in Live.

If I manually put slash ("/") in front of path, it works.

`<img src="/~/media/A9DCE5769ED7445CA76F984FAF63A7D7.ashx?la=en" />`

I know that (~) means root, but sitecore doesn't catch it.
Do I have to always put slash manually????

I have checked this https://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2012/12/sitecore-idiosyncrasies-media-urls.aspx

But, I'm really looking for the simplest way to fix this issue. (I'm using 7.0)

**============ Update ===============**

I have changed prefix like "/-/media", but still NOT working!!!

Comment: Normally, URL resolution works pretty well out of the box... Do you have any custom code in the httpBeginRequest pipeline or any changes to the default LinkManager?

Comment: How do you generate link to media in view?

Comment: In page editor, click RichTextEditor field, click Image icon in design mode, browse image file I want to and add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing only one line in Web.config file.

```
<setting name="Media.MediaLinkPrefix" value="//~/media" />
```

But, I don't know why I have to **add two slashes**. One slash is not working (same as "~/media")

Is there anybody know why???????